# Delete rows from CSV

Tags: c#, ssis

I need to remove rows from CSV file using C# in SSIS

Here is my file

```
XXXX,,,,,,,
XXXX111,,,,,,,
XXXX222,,,,,,,
A,b,c,d,e,f
g,h,i,j,k,l
1,2,3,4,5,6
,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Here is how my output should look like

```
A,b,c,d,e,f
g,h,i,j,k,l
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Basically i need to remove

```
XXXX,,,,,,,
XXXX111,,,,,,,
XXXX222,,,,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to remove those rows? Think about the rules, and show us how far you've got implementing them, and it'll be possible to help you out.

Comment: you need a criteria for removal.  Any row with and empty columns? any row with columns more than one character? etc.

Comment: Can I do based on number of times commas occur simultaneously ? Like remove rows where have more than 5 commas simultaneously like ,,,,, ?

Comment: Here's the code you want: `foreach (var line in ReadAllLines()); { if (IsGoodLine(line)) WriteLine(line); }`.  Implementing `ReadAllLines()`, `IsGoodLine()` and `WriteLine()` are an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution based on your 5 commas criteria

```
List<String> lines = new List<string>();
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    lines.Add(line);
}

lines.RemoveAll(l => l.Contains(",,,,,"));
```

Then you can write it back out or whatever you'd like

Writing out :

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter outfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outputPath))
{
      outfile.Write(String.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, lines.ToArray()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you , how do do I write back to CSV , I am new to C# . I will really appreciate your response.